# Requires clause with inner template

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename M> struct monadEv {
    // M<A> pure(A a)
    // M<B> flatMap(M<A> ma, std::function<M<B> (A)> f)

    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
};

template<template<typename> typename M> concept MonadPure =  template<typename A> requires(A a) {
    { monadEv::pure(a) } -> M<A>;
};

template<template<typename> typename M> concept Monad = monadEv<M>::is_instance && MonadPure<M>;
```

The above example does not compile because it is invalid to place a template on the right hand side of a definition, which is where I've placed it in `concept MonadPure`. I've also tried inside the `{}`s in the `requires`.

I've been following https://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/type-classes/ and trying to use it in C++20's new concept system, and I've run into a problem with making the `Monad` concept obey the typing rules for `pure`.

Is it possible to require `M#pure` returning `M<A>` for all `A`?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549046/2069064). This is arguably a dupe?

Comment: @Barry while it is probably a duplicate question, I want to avoid adding more type variables to the concept, which there seems to not be an answer for.

Comment: My answer does not suggest adding more type parameters to the concept...

Comment: I want `template<template<typename>> M> concept MonadPure`, not `template<template<typename>> M, typename A> MonadPure`, because then I can `template<template<typename>> M> concept Monad = /* ... */ && MonadPure<M>`. Edit: Oh I see. I didn't understand `secret`.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want. If you read the answer, you'll see that it does not, in fact, suggest adding extra type parameters to the concept.......