# Concept for a function returning a templated entity

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I've been experimenting with adding concepts to a [constexpr json parser](https://github.com/lefticus/constexpr_all_the_things) and am struggling to define the proper `Parser` concept. My first attempt:

```cpp
using parse_input_t = std::string_view;
template <typename T>
using parse_result_t = std::optional<std::pair<T, std::string_view>>;

// A parser for type `T` is a function: parse_input_t -> parse_result_t<T>
template <typename F, typename T>
concept Parser = std::is_invocable_r_v<parse_result_t<T>, F, parse_input_t>;
```

The problem with this is that I want to write functions with the signature:

```cpp
template <Parser P>
auto func(P p);
```

That is, I don't want `T` in the interface.

I can accomplish what I want with something kind of ugly:

```cpp
template <typename F>
concept Parser = requires(F f, parse_input_t i)
{
    requires requires(typename decltype(f(i))::value_type result)
    {      
        { f(i) } -> std::same_as<parse_result_t<decltype(result.first)>>;
    };
};
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I was hoping for something like:

```cpp
template <typename F>
concept Parser = requires(F f, parse_input_t i)
{
    { f(i) } -> std::same_as<parse_result_t<auto>>;
};
```

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547534/templated-requires-expression.  Looks like the answer is no.

Comment: [This](https://wandbox.org/permlink/siLhJS76Nz1OXooG) ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do this.

Define a type trait to pull out the `T` from `std::optional<std::pair<T, std::string_view>>`:

```
template <typename T>
struct parser_type;
template <typename T>
struct parser_type<std::optional<std::pair<T, std::string_view>>> {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T>
using parser_type_t = typename parser_type<T>::type;
```

Define a type trait around that that attempts to pull out the `T` from when you invoke `F`:

```
template <typename F>
using parser_result = parser_type_t<std::invoke_result_t<F, std::string_view>>;
```

and build a concept around that:

```
template <typename F>
concept Parser = requires {
    typename parser_result<F>;
};
```

You can then use `parser_result<F>` as the *associated type* of the parser. For example:

```cpp
struct Ints {
    auto operator()(std::string_view) -> std::optional<std::pair<int, std::string_view>>;
};

static_assert(Parser<Ints>);
static_assert(std::same_as<int, parser_result<Ints>>);
```

Comment: Add a level of indirection!  Of course!  I like this much better than my triple `requires`.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a helper trait that verifies if a given type is `parse_result_t`, then use it in the concept on `decltype(f(i))`:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_parse_result_v = false;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_parse_result_v<parse_result_t<T>> = true;

template <typename F>
concept Parser = requires(F f, parse_input_t i)
{
    f(i);
    requires is_parse_result_v<decltype(f(i))>;
};
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qWxVdaakTb9LrDZn)

---

Alternatively, use the helper trait in a separate concept definition, so as to avoid `decltype`:

```
template <typename T>
concept is_parse_result = is_parse_result_v<T>;

template <typename F>
concept Parser = requires(F f, parse_input_t i)
{
    { f(i) } -> is_parse_result;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OyGKZnOYeX3NaZY0)

Comment: Thanks for another great answer!

Comment: @ptb Updated with a friendlier syntax

Comment: Thanks!  I like how clean this is looking.  I'm looking forward to seeing some "concepts best practices" in the future.